# Factoristaion of $x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

My question revolves around the polynomial
$$x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$$
I know that it can be factorised into
$$(x^2+x+1)(x^6+x^3+1)$$
but what method can we employ to obtain this result in the first place? Any method that works will be of great help to me.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: The roots of the degree $8$ polynomial are all the ninth roots of unity (except for $1$).  The roots of the quadratic are the non-trivial cube roots of unity, so of course the one divides the other.

Comment: @lulu That's extremely interesting, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method 1: Use what you know about polynomials of the form $x^n-1$. For instance, your polynomial is $\frac{x^9-1}{x-1}$. So if you can factor the numerator, many of those factors would be inherited to your polynomial. And indeed, we have
$$
x^9-1=(x^3)^3-1=((x^3)^2+x^3+1)(x^3-1)\\
=(x^6+x^3+1)(x^2+x+1)(x-1)
$$
Put this into the fraction above, and the factorisation follows.

Method 2: Inspection. There are nine terms. They can be grouped three-by-three:
$$
(x^8+x^7+x^6)+(x^5+x^4+x^3)+(x^2+x+1)\\
=x^6(x^2+x+1)+x^3(x^2+x+1)+(x^2+x+1)
$$
and the factorisation follows.

Comment: Thank you Arthur, I particularly like the the first method. Is the 2nd method commonly used? Also, is the 2nd method assuming that there is a quadratic factor?

Comment: @A-levelStudent No, the second method is spotting that the polynomial consists of a repeating pattern, each in higher degree than the previous. It's basically luck-based, but experience helps. An alternative pattern to discover would be $$(x^8+x^5+x^2)+(x^7+x^4+x)+(x^6+x^3+1)$$with the same end result.

Comment: Then of course there is the matter of the roots of unity. Your polynomial has all the ninth-roots except 1 (my fraction in method 1 says as much), which is to say the primitive ninth roots, and the primitive third roots. The primitive third roots correspond to a factor $x^2+x+1$, and the second factor, corresponding to the primitive ninth roots, can be found through long division if you don't already know it.

Comment: I see, ok. That's very interesting, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The essential key to answering your question is to recognize that your polynomial is $(x^9-1)\big/(x-1)$.

Thus, in effect, you’re asking for the complete factorization into $\Bbb Z$-irreducible factors, of $x^9-1$. @Arthur, who gave the excellent answer that you accepted, undoubtedly knows all I’m about to say, but he kindly and reticently decided not to overwhelm you. I, being neither kind nor reticent, am about to charge ahead and attempt to give you a comprehensible explanation of (at least some of) the big picture.

The complete factorization of $x^9-1$ is $\Phi_1(x)\Phi_3(x)\Phi_9(x)$, where the Phi’s are *cyclotomic polynomials*: $\Phi_d(x)$ is the (necessarily integral) polynomial whose roots are all the primitive $d$-th roots of unity in $\Bbb C$. These all are $\Bbb Z$-irreducible: easy to show irreducibility when $d$ is a prime power, but requiring a rather more advanced proof otherwise.

The complete factorization of $x^n-1$ is:
$$
x^n-1=\prod_{d|n}\Phi_d(x)\,,
$$
and I’ll justify this way further on, perhaps long after you’ve quit reading. (“tl;dnr”)

But if you’ll accept this for now, I’ll turn the displayed formula into a method of writing down these mysterious $\Phi_d$’s.

It involves a multiplicative application of the famous *Möbius Inversion Formula*. The standard additive version says that if $F$ and $G$ are functions defined on the positive integers (with value in any given abelian group) such that
$$
\text{If}\quad(\forall n\ge1)\bigl(G(n)=\sum_{d|n}F(d)\bigr)\quad\text{then}\quad
(\forall n\ge1)\bigl(F(n)=\sum_{d|n}\mu(n/d)G(d)\bigr)\,.
$$
Here, $\mu$ is the *Möbius function*: $\mu(m)=0$ unless $m$ is square-free, and in that case, $\mu(m)$ is $-1$ to a power equal to the number of prime factors of $m$. So $\mu(10)=1$, $\mu(11)=-1$, and $\mu(12)=0$. The proof may be tricky, but involves nothing fancy.

Now, you can see that the multiplicative version of the Inversion Formula is:
$$
G(n)=\prod_{d|n}F(d)\quad\Longrightarrow\quad F(n)=\prod_{d|n}G(d)^{\mu(n/d)}
$$

Well, my displayed formula is in exactly the format required by multiplicative Möbius, so that we have the resulting:
$$
\Phi(n)=\prod_{d|n}(x^d-1)^{\mu(n/d)}
$$

We apply this to see what $\Phi_9$, $\Phi_3$, and $\Phi_1$ are: it’s easier in this case, ’cause the only divisors of $9$ are $1,3,9$, and we get
$\Phi_1(x)=x-1$, $\Phi_3(x)=(x^3-1)(x-1)^{-1}=x^2+x+1$, and $\Phi_9(x)=(x^9-1)(x^3-1)^{-1}(x-1)^0=(x^9-1)/(x^3-1)=x^6+x^3+1$. And there are your three factors of $x^9-1$.

Well, justifying my first displayed formula is not hard, but involves using the group theory of cyclic groups, easy enough, but it’s late, I’m getting tired, and will skip that. But if you’re interested, let me know, and I’ll do an edit-addendum.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for giving such a detailed and informative answer!! Unfortunately I am still in high school, so currently I know too little of number theory and abstract algebra/linear algebra (which I think are the areas you're answer comes from, correct me if I'm wrong), so currently it is pretty difficult to follow the thread all the way through. Once I have learnt the sufficient topics I will come back to this answer and ensure I understand it.

Comment: Right. I didn’t know where you were in your mathematical travels; perhaps I might have pitched my answer somewhat differently. What you can certainly do, with your current level of training, is take some interesting number, like maybe $n=30$, and use the final displayed formula to write down $\Phi(k)$ for $k=1,2,3,5,6,10, 15$ and $30$. Make sure you understand how to calculate $\mu(m)$ for any given $m$. Once you have that, you can write down a complete factorization of $x^{30}-1$, and amaze your high-school friends.